# Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings what to do?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

[image: Pic of twtter developers app site]

So my problem is I am getting this weird error message from the title of my question and I really don´t know why. I have took the oAuth url that firebase authentification provided me and pasted into the twitter app developers site in the callback url field. So why is it telling me that I need to register it ?

Posted my code here if it is for some reason my code that has to do with it:

```
twitterRealButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Signed in to twitter successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        handleTwitterSignIn(result.data);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed. No internet or No Twitter app found on your phone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
                twitterRealButton.performClick();
}

 private void handleTwitterSignIn(TwitterSession session){
        AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(session.getAuthToken().token,
                session.getAuthToken().secret);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Signed in firebase twitter successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Auth firebase twitter failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is really weird and I don´t know why this has worked but for some reason if you add: twittersdk:// as your callback url it works I guess ?